# How can I access Unpermitted Parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Lets say I have the code

```
params.require(:foo).permit(:a, :b, :c)
```

and the params came in as

```
params: {:foo => {a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3}}
```

I would get

```
unpermitted paramter: d
```

How can I access unpermitted parameters in the controller, or see if any were passed by the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c2494fe88ea7eccf47debb0fbef2b80a3bf92e65/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L205) of `ActionController::Parameters`:

You'll need to set this (in an initializer or otherwise): 
`ActionController::Parameters.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise`

This will raise a new `ActionController::UnpermittedParameters` exception which you can intercept and extract the unpermitted parameters.